# How to return results filtered on relations count to a view in RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically, I defined a property on my model which returns true or false depending on values in another table.

What I want is to have my Index action in the controller to return only those results that meet this condition.

I tried this:

```
#What I've tried on my Controller:
def index
   @projects = Project.where(:is_available?)
end

#What I've on my Controller:
def index
   @projects = Project.all
end

#What I've on my Model:
def is_available?
   workers.count<2 ? true : false
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Why your code doesn't work?**

```
Project.where(:is_available?)
```

Here in the where method, you have to pass a hash of arguments OR a string of (SQL) conditions. What you are trying to do here is to select all projects where the method is_available? returns true. The problem is that the method `is_available?` is a Ruby method (defined in your model). Since it is a Ruby function, you can't call it inside SQL. The where method is expecting SQL conditions, not ruby code.

(Thanks to @benzado for the comment)

---

**To fix your problem:**

This is what you are looking for, computed only at the db level:

```
Project.joins(:workers)
       .select('projects.*')
       .group('projects.id')
       .having('COUNT(workers.*) > 2')
```

This should returns all project having at least 2 workers associated with.

---

**How to improve this?**

You can make a **scope** of this query, to use it everywhere easily:

```
#in your model
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :having_more_than_x_workers, lambda do |workers_count|
    joins(:workers).select('projects.*').group('projects.id').having("COUNT(workers.*) > #{workers_count || 0}")
  end

end
```

To use it, in your controller for example:

```
#in your controller
def index
   @projects = Project.having_more_than_x_workers(2)
end
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but you don't explain *why* @met.lord's code wasn't working. Feel free to copy anything from my answer into yours to improve this one.

Answer (score 3):

The Rails query methods (like `where`) work by creating a database query; in other words, you can't use an attribute in `where` unless it actually exists on your data model. Otherwise, the database doesn't know about it and can't perform the filtering for you.

In your case, you should define a method on the `Project` class which performs the "is available?" query, so you can use your method in place of `where`. You can do it like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.available_projects
     where('workers_count > 2')
  end
end
```

See [MrYoshiji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14818248/10947) for specifics on how to write the query or how to define it as a named scope.