# Can you select unique by count in Rails Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

If you can't do it, how would SQL do it?

Basically I want to select all my question objects where there is at least two with the same attribute. That attribute is called, lets say, `word_id`.

So how would I only select all the objects that that share only once a common attribute with another object?

If I have three objects :

```
# Question(id: 1, word_id: 1)
# Question(id: 2, word_id: 2)
# Question(id: 3, word_id: 2)
# Question(id: 4, word_id: 1)
# Question(id: 5, word_id: 1)
# Question(id: 6, word_id: 1)
```

I would want to return just id's `2` and `3` since they both share a common attribute twice.

Is that possible? I crudely do this by making two calls to the DB where first I call all the objects in question, add them to an array, and subtract from that array objects that match my requirements. I was just curious if there was a more elegant way to do it all at once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818068/how-to-return-results-filtered-on-relations-count-to-a-view-in-rails/14818248#14818248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE world_id IN (
    SELECT world_id FROM questions GROUP BY world_id HAVING count(*) = 2
)
```

Rails:

```
Question.where("world_id IN (?)", Question.find(:all, select: "world_id", 
                                                group: "world_id HAVING count(*) = 2"))
```

I guess that's still two queries though...

Comment: Wow that and the comment above is awesome. Thanks so much guys!