# Rails ActiveRecord find User where Products equals 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model User that has_many Product(s), but some Users don't have any products yet. I want to write a query that gives me all the Users who don't current have any Products i.e. a User where Product is 0.

The only ways I can think to do this are pretty ugly. For example, getting all Users (User.all), then iterating through all the Users and checking @user.products < 1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
User.includes(:products)
     .select('users.*')
     .group('users.id')
     .having('COUNT(products.*) = 0')
```

Took from my other answer:

- [How to return results filtered on relations count to a view in RAILS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818068/how-to-return-results-filtered-on-relations-count-to-a-view-in-rails/14818248#14818248)

Edit #1:
This is an other solution:

```
User.where('users.id NOT IN (?)', Product.all.pluck(:user_id).uniq.compact)
```

It retrieves all the `user_id`s in the `products` table and select all User that are not in this `user_id`s list.

Comment: both queries fail for me. not sure why the first one fails but i think using the "!" for uniq! and compact! is making it fail. removing them seems to work.

Comment: Okay yeah I don't know why I added the ! at the end... Can you accept the answer @botbot ?

Comment: Oh and to answer your first comment, the first instruction works on PostGreSQL, it might need some change(s) for MySQL. And this first solution is the most performant!

Comment: yeah, the first one gives me an error in mySQL. but the second one now works without "!" thanks man. i didn't know about pluck so thanks for that too! answer accepted.