# Rails SQL Where Count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, count

I have a Posts Table and A Sec_photo table :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sec_photos
```

I am trying to do an advanced search form where it finds `posts` based on their sum of `sec_photos` :
`@posts = @posts.where(:sec_photos.count > 2)` is failing and I have looked online and attempted many other solutions but none seem to  work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

*Ps:* It's a necessity for the line to be in the form `@posts = @posts.where` as that coincides with other conditions.

The advanced search from searches for other fields like category_id and location_id as such

```
@posts = Post.all
     @posts = @posts.where('category_id = ?', @advanced_search.category_search) if @advanced_search.category_search.present?
     @posts = @posts.where('location_id = ?', @advanced_search.location_search) if @advanced_search.location_search.present?
     @posts = @posts.where("strftime('%m %Y', created_at) = ?", @advanced_search.newdate_search.strftime('%m %Y')) if @advanced_search.newdate_search.present?
```

The last option would be to show posts with sec_photos either more than 2 or less than 2

Comment: Are you using that query alone or combining with others queries?

Comment: Don't call `Post.all` if you are using Rails 3: It actually triggers the SQL query. Use `Post.scoped` to return the default scope without triggering the SQL query (if using Rails 4: `Post.where(nil)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198963/with-rails-4-model-scoped-is-deprecated-but-model-all-cant-replace-it)

Comment: I've changed `@posts = Post.all` to `@posts = Post.where(nil)` but i still get the same error `SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT posts.* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "sec_photos" ON "sec_photos"."post_id" = "posts"."id" GROUP BY posts.id HAVING COUNT(sec_photos.*) > 2`

Comment: Try changing the HAVING clause to `COUNT(sec_photos.id)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do as following:

```
@posts = Post.whatever_scopes_you_use
@posts = @posts.joins(:sec_photos).group('posts.id').having('COUNT(sec_photos.id)
> 2')
```

This last line will select all `posts` **having strictly more than 2** `sec_photos` associated. Of course, you can easily make a `scope` from this, accepting a `count` variable to make it dynamic ;-)

---

From my previous answer: [How to return results filtered on relations count to a view in RAILS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818068/how-to-return-results-filtered-on-relations-count-to-a-view-in-rails/14818248#14818248)

Comment: This gives me this error 'SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "sec_photos" ON "sec_photos"."post_id" = "posts"."id" GROUP BY posts.id HAVING COUNT(sec_photos.*) > 2'

Comment: I detailed my question a bit more

Comment: This error comes from the SELECT clause: `SELECT "posts".`: The query is not selecting anything at all, and I don't know why. You could force it to select everything by adding `.select('posts.*')` to your scope