# Two conditions for a database call in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails app that has *posts* and *categories*.

In the index view it should show a list of posts per category with two conditions:

- Categories has some posts
- Posts are not older than 30 days

How could I to include the second condition in this, my controller?

```
def index
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.count > 0}
end
```

Note:
I tried the following, but it still shows posts older than 30 days:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.count > 0 && c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 30.days.ago])  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution implemented with *includes* is:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 30.days.ago]).count > 0}
```

The MrYoshiji solution also works using *joins* instead of *includes*.

Extra: you can check a soluiton implementing an extra condition over the same logic in this question:

[Sort two set of instances based on one of them - Views - Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082914/sort-two-set-of-instances-based-on-one-of-them-views-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3):

You could do as the following:

```
Category.joins(:posts)
        .select('categories.*')
        .group('categories.id')
        .where('posts.created_at > ?', 30.days.ago)
        .having('COUNT(posts.*) > 0')
```

This will return:

> categories having at least 1 "recent" post which is/are maximum 30 days old

---

From my previous answer: [How to return results filtered on relations count to a view in RAILS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818068/how-to-return-results-filtered-on-relations-count-to-a-view-in-rails/14818248#14818248)

Comment: Couldn't this to be done without using joins? I got problems with my view when following your way. I guess has to be some way to do something like this `@categories = Category.includes(:posts).where(['created_at > ?', 30.days.ago]).select{|c| c.posts.count > 0} `

Comment: It can be done with Ruby but it will cost a lot more performances. What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I couldn't get it working right but I finally found the way. Like this:
`@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 30.days.ago]).count > 0}` Do you think this would use lot of resources? 
By the way, I am stuck when trying to sort both models based on the post creation date, here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082914/sort-two-set-of-instances-based-on-one-of-them-views-ruby-on-rails)
Maybe you'd like to help me also there! Thanks.

Comment: The way you do it triggers a SQL `COUNT` on every Category record, which can be a huge waste of performances depending on the amount of Category records. Why did my solution not work for you? (for the other question I will look at it)