# Sort two set of instances based on one of them - Views - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

The RoR App has posts and categories, the main view is a row set of categories/posts. It shows posts (newer than 3 days) per category. Empty categories are not shown.

I want to sort the index view to show first the categories with more recent posts. So when a new post is created for a category, the category goes up to the first "row" of the app. Inside a category, posts should be also sorted from newer to older.

Therefore I need to implement two levels of sorting, categories with newest post go first and posts are sorted by creation date inside a category. I am really stuck, how would you implement this?

My controller:

```
def index
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).select{|c| c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).count > 0} 
end
```

My view:

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  # show category name
     <% category.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).each do |post| %>
     # show post title and date
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**UPDATE:** to show what I've tried so far:

I tried to sort the @categories first, based on the posts' creation_date (as explained, Category has_many:posts). In my controller:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order('posts.created_at').select{|c| c.posts.where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).count > 0}
```

Then in my view, sort the posts as they are loaded:

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  # show category name
     <% category.posts.order('created_at').where(['created_at > ?', 3.days.ago]).each do |post| %>
     # show post title and date
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Regarding the counter_cache sugestion; I understand it'd be only for optimization of database calls, although not strictly necessary.

**SOLUTION**: it can be done as stated in the previous UPDATE; but with the change of *order('posts.created_at')* per *order('posts.created_at DESC')* in the controller; and the change of *order('created_at')* per *order('created_at DESC')* in the view.

Comment: You should show us what you've done so far - regarding the sorting.

Comment: It seems to be a typical usage of counter_cache: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See SOLUTION in the original post. 
Thanks a lot to all the open-handed contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following? (sorry for the `joins` but it will be faster)

```
Category.joins(:posts)
        .select('categories.*')
        .group('categories.id')
        .where('posts.created_at > ?', 30.days.ago)
        .having('COUNT(posts.*) > 0')
        .order('posts.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: It gives me syntax errors like: `SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT categories.* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE (posts.created_at > '2015-02-16 18:53:39.638342') GROUP BY categories.id HAVING COUNT(posts.*) > 0  ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC` 
I don't know how to manage :joins; but your proposal geve me the key as the posts need to be sorted by created_at DESC. I was missing the DESC; the same for categories.

Comment: Regarding the .includes vs .joins; based in what is explain here [link]http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/ ; and considering my expected number of categories <15; I think the optimal in this case is to use .includes to eage load everything from the begining and save later database queries. 

Anyway, thanks a lot MrYoshiji